# LESS really doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

Simple example:
if I write in less-file so:

```
h1 {
  color: #25d14d;
 }
```

in css I get:

```
h1 {
   color: #25d14d;
   }
```

But if I write:

```
@color: #25d14d;
 h1 {
   color: @color;
 }
```

I get:

```
/*
   Compile Error. 
   See error list for details
*/
```

I've read a lot of information, but none of those solutions helped.

I reset my VS 2012, reset Web Essentials, installed  ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2. and ... nothing changed.

I am in despair... How to get to work LESS with Web Essentials in VS 2012?

Comment: it's always a good idea to try to compile your LESS on independent box: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler. It is compiled just fine there, so the problem is your box not LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following workaround - start your .less file with valid CSS code, for example

```
h1 {}
```

and below put your LESS code:

```
@color: #25d14d;
 h1 {
   color: @color;
 }
```

I've faced the same problem and that helped me unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can not check whether it is working. Because it worked after updating the Windows.